# Update external installed app from Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

Some days ago, I installed an app downloading it directly from the enterprise server. Today, an update was uploaded to the Play Store, but there, I can not see the update button to automatically update the app, I just can open it or uninstall it.

The app is signed with the same certificate and has a newer version code. It is programmed with ionic but I do not thing that matters.

I need a solution to install an app from outside Play Store, while keeping Play Store updating it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are side-loaded versions just newer from those in PlayStore or are these versions internal versions that are never released on PlayStore? Because I stil don't see the advantage of side-loading an app when it can be installed from PlayStore as well.

Comment: As @Robert rightly said, they could be internal or beta or yet to be submitted to Play Store or submitted but awaiting Play Store approval. Best is to ask the developers citing your concerns

Comment: And yet another possibility which I noticed happens sometimes - update button doesn't show. Click back to exit and try again. After a few attempts, it may show

Comment: Have you ever once updated the app from the Play Store? If you uninstall the app, can you actually fresh install the newer version from the Play Store?

Comment: @Robert The app is uploaded with the same code version to the enterprise server and to the Play Store. I can see that I have the 1.2.0 versions installed while Play Store is showing that the latest version is 1.3.3. The advantage is to install the app on a smartphone without Play Store account, and then, bind the account and automatically get updates.

Comment: @beeshyams I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yep, I do not have any problem when I install the app firstly from the Play Store, but I need the first installation to be made from the outside.

Comment: @camgt The displayed version string is meaningless - it is just displayed but not used by PlaySTore. I am talking about the `versionCode` in the ´AndroidManifest.xml`. This is the relevant version number.

Comment: @Robert Yes, the `versionCode` is also newer. From 10200 to 10303 specifically.